# Awesome GNOME recognizes my media keys but fails to act upon them

Tags: gnome, awesome, key-mapping

I'm using [Awesome GNOME](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome).

When I log into the GNOME Shell, my up and down volume keys work. When I login to Awesome GNOME, they don't. However, when I go into `gnome-control-center` to set them, the Keyboard section recognizes them just fine when I go to bind the keys to the volume actions. Basically I think what's happening is that GNOME understands the keys but doesn't have anything running to act upon them.

How can I make Awesome GNOME work with the media keys?

Note that I'm on Arch Linux, so I'm using GNOME 3.8 and Awesome 3.5.1 Ruby Tuesday. I'm using the `awesome-gnome` package from Arch's AUR. Also, the play/pause key doesn't work, but I didn't test this in the GNOME Shell.

Comment: create a keybinding for your keys in your awesome config and lunch the appropriate programs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but in plain old Xorg Gnome 3. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @jairbow that sounds like a different problem. you should ask a new question.